# Replacing .net remoting to either WEB API, WCF, SignalR or Akka.net

Tags: .net, wcf, asp.net-web-api, remoting, akka.net

I have a web application which communicates with a widnows service through .net remoting. These applications are on the same server and working fine. The web application has a button which triggers to start a function in windows service using .net remoting.
Now we are going to put web application on cloud whereas the windows service will be on the client side and the communication will be held by web API between these two. We just need the same functionality to trigger the function in windows service. Can you please suggest me what is the best solution? Can I use one of the following options?

- Web API (As I'm already using between these two apps).
- WCF (It could be more pain to maintain both services at the same time).
- SignalR (is it the option to use for my scenario?)
- Akka.net (I've heard one of my colleagues said it's an option too).

Please suggest me with the best solution and also provide an example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka.Remote is an easy tool you can use to replace this same functionality without having to write the serialization or connection management bits yourself. It should work pretty much out of the box. Here's a sample: https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/tree/dev/src/examples/Chat

Comment: Hi Aaronontheweb, I've very little knowledge on Akka but i've followed the link and created a sample app which is working fine. A few things more I need to clear.
- Will this work fine if I deploy my Web API on Azure and keep the client app on client's machine?
- Can i get akndowldegement from the client once the message is received and processed?
Please suggest.
Thanks.

Comment: Yep, you can - you just need to send a reply back to the remote actor on the other end of the wire. Although for client-server type apps Akka.Remote may not be the best choice since it's designed to help form peer-to-peer networks, thus it requires opening an inbound endpoint on both ends of the connection. That can be tricky if you're deploying software to a client's machine.

Answer (score 2):

Web Api is a good choice. If you need to update data on client side in real time (windows service) you can use signalR with web api.